# Vendor Prefix Inline Style

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to write a vendor prefix to an inline style?

For example the prefix "::-webkit-color-swatch" works inside a stylesheet but how can it be written inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add vendor prefixes to inline styles, but `::-webkit-color-swatch` is not a vendor prefix, it's a pseudo element. You can only add inline styles that style a single element (the one on which the inline style is set).

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I should have realized by the double colon. Thank you Sjors!

Comment: You're welcome! Can you mark the question as answered?

Comment: Yea I'm trying to, it makes me wait 5 minutes though. Patience 